# Detect mobile OS language - angularJs

Tags: android, iphone, angularjs, cordova, mobile

I am developing a mobile application using angularJs (app will be compiled using Cordova).
Is there any way to detect the language of the mobile OS?

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-globalization.git
```

After adding Use it like this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
   console.log(navigator.globalization);
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
   function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
   function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
);
}
```

Use this Cordova plugin . Thanks :)